# PongWebSocketFrame unsupported by Internet Explorer

Tags: java, internet-explorer, websocket, errai

I've been developing a GWT application making use of the Errai Messaging. Everything worked fine until i enabled Websocket by adding "errai.bus.enable_web_socket_server=true" in the ErraiService.properties file.

No problems showed up until i tried to run on Internet Explorer, when the first message is send between client - server the following is shown and the message never reaches the other side.

> java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: io.netty.handler.codec.http.websocketx.PongWebSocketFrame frame types not supported
>       at org.jboss.errai.bus.server.io.websockets.WebSocketServerHandler.handleWebSocketFrame(WebSocketServerHandler.java:144)
>       at org.jboss.errai.bus.server.io.websockets.WebSocketServerHandler.messageReceived(WebSocketServerHandler.java:108)
>       at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:75)
>       at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:580)
>       at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:814)
>       at io.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:297)
>       at io.netty.handler.codec.replay.ReplayingDecoder.unfoldAndFireMessageReceived(ReplayingDecoder.java:524)
>       at io.netty.handler.codec.replay.ReplayingDecoder.callDecode(ReplayingDecoder.java:500)
>       at io.netty.handler.codec.replay.ReplayingDecoder.messageReceived(ReplayingDecoder.java:437)
>       at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:75)
>       at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:580)
>       at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:575)
>       at io.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:269)
>       at io.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:256)
>       at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:89)
>       at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.processSelectedKeys(AbstractNioWorker.java:301)
>       at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:220)
>       at io.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:43)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

This only occurs while running in Internet Explorer. As far as i can find IE should be supporting Websocket. I've been looking around the web for more information surrounding this problem but was unable to find anything useful.
Hopefully you can tell me more about this and what i can do about it.

Answer (score 0):

I can ensure you Internet Explorer 11 supports the ping frames and replies with a pong. I know because I just tried. I have an implementation of a WebSocket server that uses pings and pongs to check for connection liveness and for latency measurement, and I have checked that IE is actually getting pings and replying with pongs.

So the problem must be something else related with Errai or GWT.